# How to get Java, Java EE and Hibernate plugins for Eclipse Helios by yum?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, centos, yum

I need Java, Java-EE, and Hibernate plugins for Eclipse Helios. I installed Eclipse Helios in Cent OS using the following command:

```
yum install eclipse-platform
```

But it does not contain any plugins. I want to work with Java, Java EE and Hibernate. From where can I get the plugins?

Comment: Check the eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use yum to install Eclipse. It's far better to get it from the eclipse.org web site. Remove whatever you've installed via yum, then go to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads and get the package you want. Install that, and then make sure you're using the Sun/Oracle JDK, not gcj, by specifying it as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Answer (score 0):

Why not check Help->Eclipse Marketplace menu and search for whatever you want.

Comment: I dont have a option in my eclipse..I tried through adding install new software option but i failed...

Comment: Eclipse Marketplace wasn't present in all packages in Helios. Go by the answer provided by E-Riz. It is always better to get standalone software directly from the source rather than relying on OS package maintainers whose database may be years out of date.